# How can I ask all my classmates to do as I want to do?

Tags: conflicts, saying-no

I’m asking this because, now I’m Romania, our high school principal made those who are grade 12 to start class from 8-9AM.

My major problem is when it comes for me to wake up on 8:00AM, so I end up being late because I don't have time to get ready.  Last year in high school, we used to start at 13:00PM.

But here’s another problem. Our principal no longer allows us to enter in class other than from 9:00AM or 8:00AM. And because of this rule, we are marked absent when late.

**My question is:** How can I ask all my classmates to come with me and  ask our principal to change the time table? How can I determine which other classmates will join me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem seems to be more about how to deal with that situation rather than talking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In college my classmates and I were very unhappy with our professor's ability to teach so we planned to go to the Dean and request a change.

I am a little confused on what you mean by ask, if you mean privately or publicly, so I'll give a suggestion for both.

Publicly: When you and your colleagues are alone, just get their view on the change. If they see it as a problem as well plan a time to go to the principle.

**What we ended up doing**

Privately: We ended up making a GroupMe(any group messaging app would work) and passed a note with information on how to join(you could also add your reason on the note) while in class. Then when everyone connects, you can discuss your plans to meet the principle. This can keep you anonymous if you like.

Comment: Well, I want to have strong influence over others for my interest only. Is it possible to be done? And also, how can I tell my classmates that our time table is bad? So that we can all of us go to principle for changing time table.

Comment: If the time works for them, it would take a lot of convincing and more on the side of please do me this favor. I was answering on just getting the word out. I would first get their feelings on the subject to see how much convincing you really have to do.

Comment: Well for some it doesn’t work. Some they have problem with coming early.

Comment: You're not going to convince someone if it doesn't work for them, take the ones who think like you and go to the principle.

Comment: thanx for the advice or suggestion.